# How to use tk.StringVar() within OOP?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, tkinter

Not sure if this is my lack of understanding of tkinter or OOP (probably both), but the following code won't work. I isolated the problem in my tkinter project which I converted into OOP paradigm and narrowed it down but I can't figure out how to debug it. I know I could avoid StringVar(), by creating some custom function or workaround, but I want to stick with it because imo it's more elegant.

The complete, isolated code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        var = tk.StringVar()

        label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=var)
        label.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text='go', command=lambda: self.var_setter())
        button.pack()

    def var_setter(self):
        self.var.set('Hello')

appobject = App()
appobject.mainloop()
```

When the button is pushed it gives the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/Ed/sandbox.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    button = tk.Button(self, text='go', command=lambda: self.var_setter())
  File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/Ed/sandbox.py", line 17, in var_setter
    self.var.set('Hello')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1932, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'var'
```

I've tried

```
self.var = tk.StringVar()
```

and other ways of moving around 'self'.

I got to admit, I suspect the

```
tk.Tk.__init__(self)
```

which I took from the [sentdex tutorials on tkinter](http://pythonprogramming.net/change-show-new-frame-tkinter/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to use `self.var` everywhere, including the assignment `self.var = tk.StringVar()` and the `Label` variable `self.textvariable=var`. I made those changes and the program worked.
2. You can simplify `command=lambda: self.var_setter()` to `command=self.var_setter`. No need to wrap a basic call in a `lambda`.